# Grep information from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, grep, pattern-matching

I'm trying to grep the model from /proc/cpuinfo in Ubuntu with this     command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model'
```

But i'm getting 2 lines as output:

```
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

I will get only this line as output:

```
model       : 60
```

How can i do this?

Comment: idk if there's a full moon tonight but you have a whole bunch of crazy "answers" below. Ignore any that suggest `cat /proc/cpuinfo |` or multiple pipes, and anything that looks remotely non-trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use 'sed' to parse out individual lines.

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model' | sed -n "1p"` will give you `model: 60`

and

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model' | sed -n "2p"` will give you the second line as output.

Comment: cat | grep | sed seems a bit overkill and fragile

Comment: @fedorquiIt It might be when this operation is used inside a script meant for large scale fetching. It seemed to be a quick solution here.

Comment: This is crazy way to approach this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command for verifying the model number of the server:

```
dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'
```

To me, it returns:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: IBM
        Product Name: System x3650 M3 -[7945J4A]-
        Version: 00
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the first line simply use `head`:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model' | head -1   # <--- This is what you realy asked
```

To get only the last line you can use `tail`:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model' | tail -1
```

And if you want the `n'th` line you can use both:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model' | head -n | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the lines containing "model" whose last field is a number:

```
awk '/model/ && $NF~/^[0-9]*$/ {print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

or you can even provide the pattern you want to match [using `-v`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
awk -v word="model" '$0 ~ word && $NF~/^[0-9]*$/ {print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n '/model/{p;q}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

This will "grep" for the first line matching `model` in `/proc/cpuinfo` and print it. Then it will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--invert-match` option of `grep` to remove line containing name.

```
  -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

By using `-v`  command become

```
 cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model' | grep -v 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model\s\+:'`

This greps for `model` followed by whitespace (at least 1) and followed by colon.

Comment: Why use `cat`? `grep '^model\s\+:' /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 0):

Another one approach:

```
lscpu | grep Model:
```

Seems to be quite simple

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
grep '^model[[:blank:]]*:' /proc/cpuinfo
```

or if you prefer awk:

```
awk '/^model[[:blank:]]*:/' /proc/cpuinfo
```

and then if all you want is the number at the end of the line then that's just a tweak:

```
awk '/^model[[:blank:]]*:/{ print $NF }' /proc/cpuinfo
```